# How to set PopUp Window size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I have opend a popup window using javascript. now in that popup window i have got a button and on click on that button i wants to changes size of that (current/same page) popup window.

Please tell me how we can do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE:

```
self.resizeTo(500,400);
```

Other browsers:

```
window.outerHeight = 500;
window.outerWidth = 400;
```

Those examples were from the site mentioned below:

http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/tutorials/javascript/window_1.html

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The methods you have to use are  [resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) or [resizeBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeBy).

The option to resize a window may be restricted by browser-settings.